# A little different left join with Symfony 1.4, Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-1.4

There are users:

```
id | name
 1    user1
 2    testuser
```

There are tasks:

```
id | creatorid | ownerid| name
1     1           1        task1
2     1           2        task2
3     2           1        task3
4     2           2        task4
```

I did something like that:

```
Doctrine_Core::getTable('User')->createQuery()->leftJoin('User.Task')
```

but then the tables are connected with "creatorid", and not "ownerid", how to specify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you define the `Task` relation on the `Users` table. You should have something like:

```
Tasks:
...
  relations:
    owner: {class: User, local: ownerId, foreign: id, foreignAlias: ownedTasks}
    creator: {class: User, local: creatorId, foreign: id, foreignAlias: createdTasks}
```

Then you can use:

```
Doctrine_Core::getTable('User')->createQuery()->leftJoin('User.ownedTasks)
```

to join by the owners or

```
Doctrine_Core::getTable('User')->createQuery()->leftJoin('User.createdTasks')
```

to join by the creator.

Answer (score 2):

I use Doctrine_Query

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->select('u.*, t.*')
        ->from('Users u')
        ->leftJoin('u.Tasks t ON u.id = t.creatorid');

echo $q->getSqlQuery();
```

[Doctrine 1.2 Left Join Documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language.html)